# custom routing with mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am implementing a system that has a file-folder system (users can have folders and each folder can have files or folders in it again). I want to build the Url according to the folders. lets say a user has a folder 'Folder1' and in it there is another folder 'Folder2'. When I am in Folder1 I want the Url to look like 'Home/Folder1' and when user clicks 'Folder2' in 'Folder1' Url should look like 'Home/Folder1/Folder2' and it can be able to go like this forever :)

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
//   THIS IS THE LINE I ADDED
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Home",
            "{folderPath}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", folderPath = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );      
//   END OF LINE I ADDED           
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = -1 }
        );
    }
}
```

I changed the RouteConfig file and now I am able to have 'Home/Folder1' and 'Home/Folder2' unfortunately that is not what I want :/

I hope I explained my problem clearly.if anyone can help me I would appreciate it. By the I am actually using MVC4.

Answer (score 0):

Add a * to folderPath:

```
"{*folderPath}",
```

But that will make the second route useless.

Comment: I'm not a mind reader. What doesn't work as you want? What result are you getting?
Are you trying to build the url? In this case you will have to build a url manually.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't able to express what I want clearly. I want to build the url in the way that it can show the nested folder structure like 'Home/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3' if folder 1,2 and 3 are nested in that order. Even if I am calling just Folder action of Home controller each time I itarate over the nested folder structure I need to append the folder name to Url accordingly.